# Smartphone USB issue

Tags: motorola-droid

Whenever I connect my Motorola turbo phone to my computer, it is not functioning properly.

In development settings, I have debugging and tethering on

Answer (score 0):

Connect the usb and there will be different option available 
Charging
Data transfer 
Etc 
Select what do you want to do .
If these are not available it means that your usb cable is not working perfectly